# Seeking ESP32 with display which is supported by the PlatformIO debugger

Tags: esp32, platform-io

I am switching to Platform IO as my ESP32 IDE. Alas, none of my boards are supported by the debugger. See https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/plus/debugging.html#piodebug

To save me along time searching, does anyone know of an ESP32 with built in display which is supported? I don't care which board, all that I need is WFIi and BT (or LoRa) and a built in display.

Please mote that I am not asking for "best" or anything opinion based. The accepted answer will be the first posted. I am hoping that one of you is already using the PlatformIO debugger on an ESP32 with built-in display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- TTGO LoRa32-OLED V1
- Wemos LOLIND32 PRO (TFT socket)
- Heltec LoRa32

Comment: Can you explain why those would be good?

Comment: Have you used any of them with the PlatformIO Debugger?

Comment: I use the lolin and ttgo lora32 with jtag on a daily basis on vs. Works like a charm.

Comment: @Helmar, I cannot say that the LoRa boards are good. They are somewhat acceptable. The Lolin, on the other hand, is a very good esp32 devboard.

Comment: In the end, I bought a https://www.amazon.co.uk/d/Network-Interface-Cards/ESP32-WROVER-KIT-board-Espressif-ESP32-rev/B071ZLSB2D (although, not from there)  It is a great board & does all that I want (alas, there are a maximum of 2 breakpoints supported, unless I buy a  JTAG probe, but IO can live with that, and I have call stack, variable & memory read/write, watches, etc)

Answer (score 0):

If I will accept LoRa, then I can use a [TTGO LoRa32-OLED V1](https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/boards/espressif32/ttgo-lora32-v1.html#debugging)

Answer (score 0):

I also bought myself an [ESP-WROVER-KIT-VB](https://www.espressif.com/en/products/hardware/esp-wrover-kit/overview).

It's pricey, [$39.99 on AliExpress](https://sunhokey.en.alibaba.com/product/62571938928-221082473/ESP_WROVER_KIT_VB_ESP32_wrover_development_board_with_3_2_inch_LCD.html), ***but***, it has a large screen.  Here it is, playing Doom !

[image]

Here's a [youTube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gb_JFDa0AIo) to the vieo.

The best, though, IMO, is the onboard debugger, which lets me load my program to the IDE (Visual Studio Cod + PlafotmIO), and set and run to breakpoints, examine he call stack when they hit, plus examine & change variable values, etc.

> Description:
> The ESP-WROVER-KIT from Espressif supports the most distinguishing features of the ESP32. Whether you need external SRAM for IoT applications, or an LCD+camera interface, it has you covered!
> The ESP-WROVER-KIT is a newly-launched development board built around ESP32. This board comes with an ESP32 module already. The V3 version of this kit now comes with the ESP32-WROVER. This module come with an additional 4 MB SPI PSRAM (Pseudo static RAM)
> The ESP-WROVER-KIT features support for an LCD and MicroSD card. The I/O pins have been led out from the ESP32 module for easy extension. The board carries an advanced multi-protocol USB bridge (the FTDI FT2232HL), enabling developers to use JTAG directly to debug the ESP32 through the USB interface. The development board makes secondary development easy and cost-effective.
>
> Features:
> ESP32 is engineered to be fast, smart and versatile. The ESP-WROVER-KIT complements these characteristics by offering on-board high speed Micro SD card interface, VGA camera interface, as well as 3.2” SPI LCD panel and I/O expansion capabilities.
> Bogged down by bugs. The ESP32 supports JTAG debugging, while the ESP-WROVER-KIT integrates a USB debugger as well. This makes debugging and tracing complex applications very easy, without the need for any additional hardware.
> Have you been developing your applications around the ESP-WROOM-32 module? Not only does the ESP-WROVER-KIT support the popular ESP-WROOM-32 module, but it also supports the new ESP32-WROVER module!
>
> Specifications:
> Dual core 240 MHz CPU;
> with 4 MB SPI PSRAM (Pseudo static RAM);
> Built-in USB-JTAG Debugger;
> 3.2” SPI LCD panel;
> Micro-SD card interface
> VGA camera interface
> I/O expansion
> WiKi: http://wiki.52pi.com/index.php/ESP32_WROVER_KIT_SKU:_EP-0090